# How to change parameters for a Kubeflow Pipeline Recurring Run?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I would like to run my Kubeflow pipeline every 30 minutes using a "Recurring Run". For each run I would like to tweak my parameters.  For example:

First run : START_MONTH=2019-01,END_MONTH=2010-02

Second run : START_MONTH=2019-02,END_MONTH=2010-03

and so on.

I can to pass a new json parameter to the job to each model this:

```
{ 
   1: [{"START_MONTH":"2019-01"},{"END_MONTH":"2019-02"}],
   2: [{"START_MONTH":"2019-02"},{"END_MONTH":"2019-03"}],
}
```

Now I need a way to index into the parameters based on whether the job is running for the first, second, etc. time.

Is there any way to access the job metadata inside of a pipeline to determine which "run" a job is currently on or does the job itself need to externalise this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up :

- adding a json variable to model the parameter list
- adding a string variable and defaulting it to [{{workflow.name}}](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/variables/) so it can be used to deduce which "run number" is currently being executed (e.g. myjob-xyz-1, myjob-abc-2, etc) within the pipeline.